# MSSql GUID to MySQL Migration

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064, data-migration

Currently my database is in MS SQL. I have table with 100k records. this table has a column which is primary key, auto incremented as GUID.
Recently I migrated the data to MySQL (using workbench) and it was all successful but when I try to insert any data it fails. I found that the column 'Id' was migrated as Varchar(36) and hence the rows are not getting incremented.

What is the best solution to overcome issue? This is a sample of just one table and I have around table with the same issue.

Comment: Use `NOT NULL DEFAULD (UUID())` for this column.

Comment: Will this work?

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ISP`.`StageConfigurationAudit` (
  `Id` CHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid(),
  `CreatedBy` VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL);

Comment: You are not careful. Default value expression MUST be enclosed with parenthesis. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c13474906e9fa281a74f002e4a78d827